# Convert multi-page Tesseract box file to OpenCV X, Y, width, height

Tags: opencv, image-processing, tesseract

So I have to convert multi-page box file that was generated by Tesseract to OpenCV matrix coordinates to crop image ROI. The problem was coordinate values that is written in box file is different with the image coordinate system in OpenCV.

The box files looks like this:

```
    Page 0
H 357 1494 422 1562 0
9 453 1495 515 1560 0
3 556 1494 605 1560 0
V 634 1494 694 1561 0
F 726 1495 786 1562 0
1 828 1495 854 1562 0
L 908 1495 971 1562 0

    Page 1
H 371 1369 434 1425 1
9 461 1372 519 1425 1
3 556 1373 606 1427 1
V 634 1376 694 1430 1
F 718 1378 780 1432 1
1 820 1378 846 1435 1
L 893 1379 954 1437 1
```

If I open the coordinate trough jTessBoxEditor, the number values is being converted to image coordinate system:

[jTessBoxEditor coordinates in image page 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYMWP.png)

[jTessBoxEditor coordinates in image page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGnqn.png)

[image ROI I tried to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdHQe.png)

I do understand that coordinate values in Tesseract box file is a **bottom-left** coordinate system, while OpenCV image coordinate values is **top-left**. I tried to convert those coordinate values by calculate the difference between values in box file and jTessBoxEditor, the problem was difference between those values is different for each page.

So what is the best way to convert coordinate values in multi-page box file to image coordinate system in OpenCV **for each page** without trying to calculating it one by one?